# Do any countries share passport info of all its citizens?

Tags: passports, countries

Curious how "global" passports really are, even just the minute they are made, regardless if the passport holder travels or not!

Are there countries that have an agreement with each other that they share all the country's citizens' passport info with another country?

I have a feeling maybe within EU they do this because EU is kinda like one big schengen group? Are there other countries that do this?

Comment: Google on five eyes treaty, the CIS have their own version,

Comment: In addition to the Five Eyes Treaty, the UK has special arrangements with the ROI and affluent Commonwealth, France has arrangements with former colonies in Africa and Asia. But we're talking about basic info like what's on the portrait page of the passport and not deep histories.  Also Interpol will share stop indicators.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.